# Stored procedure calling a scalar function does not run in deployment

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a web application in ASP.NET MVC deployed on a Windows Server 2012 with IIS 8, and when I call a method that runs a stored procedure that will run a scalar function it doesn't work, it doesn't give me any useful error message. I tried with Log4Net but doesn't save any log on the database. It works before deployment and I gave the database, stored procedure and function all the security permissions.

This is the stored procedure

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[CasasCercanas]
    @Latitude DECIMAL(10,6),
    @Longitude DECIMAL(10,6),
    @Distancia decimal(15,9)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT DISTINCT
        PC.IdCasa,
        dbo.CalculateDistance(@Latitude, @Longitude, PC.LatitudCasa, PC.LongitudCasa) as Distance
    FROM Casa PC
    WHERE  
        @Distancia > dbo.CalculateDistance(@Latitude, @Longitude, PC.LatitudCasa, PC.LongitudCasa) 
        AND Activo = 1
    ORDER BY  
        Distance
END
```

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but how can i deploy a function? i also using AppPool for authentification does it has something to de with the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem, i changed the default Culture and uiCulture to EN-us because i was deploying it in a german server(the owner is from germany) and the problem was that in german culture there is a different format for decimals and when it was sent to the database there was an error in the convertion, thanks for your answers.

this is the code in the WebConfig

```
<globalization enableClientBasedCulture="true" culture="en-US" uiCulture="en-US" />
```

by default it captured the SO culture so i changed it to only en-US

Answer (score 1):

First, I think there is a missing semi-colon to close the SQL query statement in the function. -- this may simply be a transcription into SO.

Next, I can offer this assistance: the WHERE clause evaluates the distance from the input lat/lon to each of the Casa locations in order to filter this distance to be < the input @Distancia. The same distance values are evaluated a 2nd time for the qualified records....this is an inefficiency.

The stored procedure (once it correctly deploys/executes) should evaluate the distance once for all Casa rows, then filter those results by @Distancia and Activ0=1 only returning those rows which satisfy both criteria.

the snippet below is the relevant change:
...

```
AS 
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   SELECT
      IdCasa, Distance
   FROM  
         (SELECT PC.IdCasa, 
                 dbo.CalculateDistance(@Latitude, @Longitude, PC.LatitudCasa,     PC.LongitudCasa) as Distance 
          FROM Casa PC 
          WHERE Activo = 1
        ) ActivoDistance
   WHERE
      @Distancia > ActivoDistance.Distance
   ORDER BY Distance;

END;
```

I hope this snippet helps make the procedure run faster once it runs correctly!

Comment: Thanks that was the query i wanted but i didnt know how to do it, it will be faster, but i still have the deployment error, it works on local debug